# LINQ query binded to gridview (problem with date)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I have problem regarding date in LINQ query which is binded to a gridview. This is the code I'm using, nothing special, but the problem is I can't format the date (p.aktivnost.aktivnost.datum is date) in gridview to be formatted like "dd.MM.yyyy." and instead it is being shown as "dd.MMM.yyyy. 0:00:00" which I want to avoid.

I've tried to search for the solution, but none of the solutions I've found were helpful. The only solution that gave me partial success was when I used "date = p.aktivnost.aktivnost_datum.Value.Day", but then I was unable to add the other values (for month and for year).

As I sad, the following code was an idea that didn't work.

> date =
>   p.aktivnost.aktivnost_datum.Value.Day
>   + "." + p.aktivnost.aktivnost_datum.Value.month
>   + "." + p.aktivnost.aktivnost_datum.Value.Day

Now, the code used for binding data. Gridview doesn't contain any columns on page load.

```
var predavaci = from p in db.predavacs
                                where p.osoba_id == idOsoba
                                orderby p.osoba.osoba_prezime
                                select new { p.aktivnost.tema.tema_naziv, p.aktivnost.ciklu.ciklus_naziv, p.aktivnost.podciklu.naziv_podciklus, p.aktivnost.aktivnost_datum, p.aktivnost.mjesto.mjesto_naziv, p.aktivnost.ciljana_grupa.ciljana_grupa_naziv };


                    gvIzvjestaj.DataSource = predavaci;
                    DataBind();

                    gvIzvjestaj.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = "Naziv aktivnosti";
                    gvIzvjestaj.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Text = "Ciklus";
                    gvIzvjestaj.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Text = "Podciklus";
                    gvIzvjestaj.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Text = "Datum";
                    gvIzvjestaj.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Text = "Mjesto";
                    gvIzvjestaj.HeaderRow.Cells[5].Text = "Ciljna grupa";}
```

**Solution:**

```
gvIzvjestaj.DataSource = predavaci.ToList().Select(p => new { p.tema_naziv, p.ciklus_naziv, p.naziv_podciklus, datum = p.aktivnost_datum.Value.Day + "." + p.aktivnost_datum.Value.Month + "." + p.aktivnost_datum.Value.Year + ".",p.mjesto_naziv,p.ciljana_grupa_naziv});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Gridview display code do something like this

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="p.aktivnost.aktivnost.datum" 
    DataFormatString="{0:MM-dd-yyyy}" HtmlEncode="false" 
    HeaderText="p.aktivnost.aktivnost.datum" />
```

EDIT

Try this:

```
var predavaci = from p in db.predavacs
where p.osoba_id == idOsoba
orderby p.osoba.osoba_prezime
select new
{
    p.aktivnost.tema.tema_naziv,
    p.aktivnost.ciklu.ciklus_naziv,
    p.aktivnost.podciklu.naziv_podciklus,
    aktivnost_datum = new {
        string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}",
        p.aktivnost.aktivnost_datum.Day,
        p.aktivnost.aktivnost_datum.Month,
        p.aktivnost.aktivnost_datum.Year)
    },
    p.aktivnost.mjesto.mjesto_naziv,
    p.aktivnost.ciljana_grupa.ciljana_grupa_naziv
};
```

Or like mentioned in another answer, you're free to edit the collection like normal once it's in memory.

```
gvIzvjestaj.DataSource = 
    predavaci.ToList().Select(q => 
        new {
            q.aktivnost.tema.tema_naziv,
            q.aktivnost.ciklu.ciklus_naziv,
            q.aktivnost.podciklu.naziv_podciklus,
            q.aktivnost.aktivnost_datum.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"),
            q.aktivnost.mjesto.mjesto_naziv,
            q.aktivnost.ciljana_grupa.ciljana_grupa_naziv
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this also isn't the solution because I don't have bound fields in my gridview because the data is binded dynamically.

Comment: The same gridview is used for different queries and depending of the user choice the griview is then generated. This isn't an option for me.

Comment: Well then what do you have control over?

Comment: What do you mean? This is what I have in .aspx

        <asp:GridView ID="gvIzvjestaj" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the first one didn't work for me, Intellisense complains about that "aktivnost_datum = new" part and neither did the second one, but as you can see from my edit in the question it was helpful!

Answer (score 2):

In your `select ... new` just write:

```
p.aktivnost.aktivnost_datum.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
```

**EDIT:**

```
var predavaci = (from p in db.predavacs
                            where p.osoba_id == idOsoba
                            orderby p.osoba.osoba_prezime).ToList().Select(p => 
  new { p.aktivnost.tema.tema_naziv, p.aktivnost.ciklu.ciklus_naziv, p.aktivnost.podciklu.naziv_podciklus, p.aktivnost.aktivnost_datum, p.aktivnost.mjesto.mjesto_naziv, p.aktivnost.ciljana_grupa.ciljana_grupa_naziv } );
```

Comment: Be aware that sorting will not work properly in this case, because the sorting will be based on string and not date.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but, that will not work because LINQ doesn't accept .toString() method. I've already tried it and it gives an error.

Comment: @Hvrach, that has to do with Linq2Sql not Linq in general. If you do the formatting in memory (see my edit above) it will work just fine.

Comment: Actually, I'm using Linq2Entities. Thank you for your answer! It was helpful!